# How can I adjust space between groups of bars AND the width of the bars AND stitch two of these together in ggplot2 with some funky code?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Here are my wonderful graphs, which Allen Cameron and others helped with.
[image: graph 1]
[image: graph 2]

What I want to do is to keep the space between BARS the same, but DECREASE space between GROUPS of bars while INCREASING each bar's size.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
head(data)

pivot_longer(data, cols = c("app", "rej","req")) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("req","app","rej")), 
         project = factor(project,levels = c("Mason",
                                              "Monadnock",
                                              "Old Harbor",
                                              "Oswegatchie",
                                              "Otter Creek",
                                              "Salina",
                                              "Tomahawk",
                                              "Vanceboro",
                                              "Wallowa Falls",
                                              "Wells",
                                              "Williams",
                                              "York Haven"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = cat)) +
  labs(x="Project", y="Number of Studies") +
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(~project, switch = "x") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.7, 0.7), labels=c("Req", "App", "Rej")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.text.x= element_text(size=8),legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), legend.background = element_rect(linetype = "solid", colour = "black")) + 
  theme(legend.title.align=0.5) + 
  labs(fill = "Study Category") + 
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Biota and Biodiversity", 
                               "Connectivity and Fragmentation",
                               "Cultural Resources",
                               "Geomorphology",
                               "Landscape and Land Cover",
                               "Recreation",
                               "Water Quantity",
                               "Water Quality"),
                    values = c("#007934", "#E37222", "#7570B3", "#FECB00", "#9E2432", "#FF69B4","#005B82","#1F82BB"))
```

And data:

```
project   cat app rej req
1          Mason    BB   9   3  12
2          Mason    CF   0   0   0
3          Mason    CR  10   0  10
4          Mason    GM   0   0   0
5          Mason    LC   0   0   0
6          Mason    RC   7   0   7
7          Mason WQUAN   1   1   2
8          Mason WQUAL   3   0   3
9      Monadnock    BB   8   0   8
10     Monadnock    CF   0   0   0
11     Monadnock    CR   4   0   4
12     Monadnock    GM   0   0   0
13     Monadnock    LC   0   0   0
14     Monadnock    RC   2   0   2
15     Monadnock WQUAN   9   0   9
16     Monadnock WQUAL   1   0   1
17    Old Harbor    BB   5   0   5
18    Old Harbor    CF   0   0   0
19    Old Harbor    CR   1   0   1
20    Old Harbor    GM   0   0   0
21    Old Harbor    LC   1   0   1
22    Old Harbor    RC   0   0   0
23    Old Harbor WQUAN   0   0   0
24    Old Harbor WQUAL   0   0   0
25   Oswegatchie    BB   5   1   6
26   Oswegatchie    CF   3   0   3
27   Oswegatchie    CR   1   0   1
28   Oswegatchie    GM   0   0   0
29   Oswegatchie    LC   1   0   1
30   Oswegatchie    RC   2   0   2
31   Oswegatchie WQUAN   3   1   4
32   Oswegatchie WQUAL   2   2   4
33   Otter Creek    BB   3   0   3
34   Otter Creek    CF   0   0   0
35   Otter Creek    CR   1   0   1
36   Otter Creek    GM   0   0   0
37   Otter Creek    LC   1   0   1
38   Otter Creek    RC   2   0   2
39   Otter Creek WQUAN   3   0   3
40   Otter Creek WQUAL   1   0   1
41        Salina    BB   5   0   5
42        Salina    CF   0   0   0
43        Salina    CR   1   0   1
44        Salina    GM   0   0   0
45        Salina    LC   0   0   0
46        Salina    RC   1   0   1
47        Salina WQUAN   0   0   0
48        Salina WQUAL   2   0   2
49      Tomahawk    BB   7   0   7
50      Tomahawk    CF   0   0   0
51      Tomahawk    CR   0   0   0
52      Tomahawk    LC   0   0   0
53      Tomahawk    RC   0   0   0
54      Tomahawk    RC   2   0   2
55      Tomahawk WQUAN   2   0   2
56      Tomahawk WQUAL   0   0   0
57     Vanceboro    BB   4   0   4
58     Vanceboro    CF   0   0   0
59     Vanceboro    CR   1   0   1
60     Vanceboro    GM   0   0   0
61     Vanceboro    LC   0   0   0
62     Vanceboro    RC   0   0   0
63     Vanceboro WQUAN   0   0   0
64     Vanceboro WQUAL   1   0   1
65 Wallowa Falls    BB  13   2  15
66 Wallowa Falls    CF   0   0   0
67 Wallowa Falls    CR   4   0   4
68 Wallowa Falls    GM   1   0   1
69 Wallowa Falls    LC   1   0   1
70 Wallowa Falls    RC   3   0   3
71 Wallowa Falls WQUAN   4   0   4
72 Wallowa Falls WQUAL   2   2   4
73         Wells    BB   4   3   7
74         Wells    CF   1   0   1
75         Wells    CR   1   0   1
76         Wells    GM   1   0   1
77         Wells    LC   0   0   0
78         Wells    RC   2   2   4
79         Wells WQUAN   0   0   0
80         Wells WQUAL   2   1   3
81      Williams    BB   9   1  10
82      Williams    CF   1   0   1
83      Williams    CR   1   0   1
84      Williams    GM   0   0   0
85      Williams    LC   0   0   0
86      Williams    RC   3   0   3
87      Williams WQUAN   1   3   4
88      Williams WQUAL   3   0   3
89    York Haven    BB   8   6  14
90    York Haven    CF   1   3   4
91    York Haven    CR   1   0   1
92    York Haven    GM   0   0   0
93    York Haven    LC   0   0   0
94    York Haven    RC   1   1   2
95    York Haven WQUAN   1   3   4
96    York Haven WQUAL   1   0   1
```

I have tried `position_dodge` and `width=` in the `geom_col()` part of the code, and it makes weird extra bars. I haven't tried to put this all together into one dealio because I haven't figured out the first part yet. HELP!!

Comment: Does decreasing the expand numbers in the line below not help? `scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.7, 0.7), labels=c("Req", "App", "Rej"))`

Comment: It's weird, it makes some of the groups close together and some further apart when I change it to scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.2, 0.2), labels=c("Req", "App", "Rej"))               Edit: I am an idiot, it just looks like that because some of the bars won't be there...

Comment: but how do I widen the bars?

Comment: Save your output with a differently-sized window.  I know it sounds strange, but the output greatly depends on the resolution and size of your graphics device.  Give it a try:  `ggsave('myplotbig.png', width=8, height=5)` and `ggsave('myplotsmall.png', width=5, height=5)`.  Compare those two and you'll see likely a massive difference in the appearance.  Just note that text sizes differently than the other stuff on your plot, so you will squish them together with a smaller width, but will also tend to make the text bigger in comparison.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it seems to do the same thing as when I adjust the options in the "export" function in R Studio.